# Определение положения в массиве

Tags: lua

Собсно есть такая кашица, как ниже будет представлено. Заметки по улучшению и конструктивная критика всегда в почете.
Собсно вопрос, есть ли возможность как то без шаманства определять позицию элемента в массиве, а то сейчас для этого использую что то на подобии :

```
function minArr(arr,value) -- сравнение значение с таблицей значений для полуения его позиции в таблице
    for i = 1, #arr do
        if(arr[i] == value) then return i end
    end
end
```

и код целиком :

```
    points = {} -- собсна точки (значения получаем отдельно из другого источника)

    --[[

    таблица точки являет собой таблицу таблиц с положением единичных точек

    points[1] = point1 --> point1 = {}; point1.x = value point1.y = value
    points[2] = point2 --> point2 = {}; point2.x = value point2.y = value
    points[3] = point3 --> point3 = {}; point3.x = value point3.y = value

    и тд

    ]]

    local marks = {} -- метки точек занята/свободна

    for i = 1, #points do -- изначально все точки свободны
        marks[i] = false
    end


    function path(arr) -- собсна шукаем путь

    local p_arr = {}
        p_arr = arr
    local counter = 1
    local minim = 0
    local position = 0
    local length_arr ={} -- таблица длин для текущей точки


    while(counter ~= #p_arr ) do

        marks[counter] = true -- сразу маркируем текущую точку как занятую

    for i = 1, #p_arr do -- посчитали, записали длины из текущей точки к остальным
        length_arr[i] = leng(p_arr[counter], p_arr[i])
    end

    minim = compare(length_arr) -- нашли минимум из посчитаных длин
    position = minArr(length_arr,minim) -- нашли позицию минимума в таблице длин

    if(marks[position] == true) then -- если вершина занята то проводим поиск минимума по новой
        while(marks[position] == true) do
            length_arr[position] = math.huge
            minim = compare(length_arr)
            position = minArr(length_arr,minim)
        end
        print("nearest to point " .. counter .. " is " .. position)
    else -- если вершина свободна то едем дальше
        print("nearest to point " .. counter .. " is " .. position)
    end

        counter = counter + 1
    end

end



    function minArr(arr,value) -- сравнение значение с таблицей значений для полуения его позиции в таблице
        for i = 1, #arr do
            if(arr[i] == value) then return i end
        end
    end


    function compare(arr) -- сравнение значений для получения наименьшего
        local minim = math.huge
        for i = 1, #arr do
            if minim > arr[i] then minim = arr[i] end
        end
            return minim
    end


    function leng(point1, point2) -- расчет длины между точками
        local n = 0
            n = math.sqrt(math.pow((point2.x - point1.x),2) + math.pow((point2.y - point1.y),2))
        return n
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `lua` массивы - это таблицы и там нету понятия как "индекс", есть понятия *ключ* и *значение*. Соответственно, чтобы получить ключ по значению, нет ничего лучше итерирования:

```
function get_key_for_value(t, value)
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if v==value then return k end
  end
  return nil
end
```

Если у вас неизменная таблица и вам нужно часто искать ключи, то можно сделать инвертированную таблицу и искать по ней:

```
function table_invert(t)
   local s={}
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
     s[v]=k
   end
   return s
end
```

Но вас ждёт сюрприз, если в вашей таблице будет несколько одинаковых значений для разных ключей.

Comment: что ж, жаль, но и на том спасибо